# How to show contents of ruby .gem file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

is it possible to show the contents if you just have the .gem file?

I found `gem contents` command stating in the help:

> The contents command lists the files in an installed gem

This works fine, but I wondered if there is a way to list the contents of a not installed gem, if I just have the built `.gem` file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gem unpack`.

```
gem unpack <gemname>.gem
```